# How to partially overlap views within a relative layout

Tags: android

I'm trying overlap the pink button over the green view, but my "z-offset" is the opposite of what I want.

Is the effect I'm looking for only achievable with frame layouts?

[image]

```
<include layout="@layout/button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"/>

<include layout="@layout/view"
    android:id="@id/view"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Comment: Swap them. That is, list the `layout/view` first.

Comment: Worked. I will check mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no `android:elevation`s involved, the `View`s are just drawn in the order they're listed in the layout, with the first one being the farthest away on the z-axis, and the last being the closest. If you want the `button` on top, move it to the end of the layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/view"
    android:id="@id/view"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<include layout="@layout/button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In relative layout, the view you add last is always on top of the other.So you just have to swap your views

First `@layout/view` then  `@layout/button`

```
<include layout="@layout/view"
    android:id="@id/view"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<include layout="@layout/button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"/>
```